# The Process Could Not Read File Due to OS Error 53

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

I have hunted high and low for a fix to this, but everything is saying the same - a permissions error. The error given in the replication monitor clearly states it, but I can't see what I have got wrong.

The set-up (sorry for all the red lines in the screenshots - doing my best to disguise stuff ;) ):

- Publisher and distributor are on SQL Server 2012 (11.0.3128)
- Subscriber is a remote SQL Server 2008 (10.50.2550) - using a pull subscription
- Windows user called SQL_Replication_Dev http://screencast.com/t/mz7ZX3fCW. This user exists on both servers with the same password
- Login for SQL_Replication_Dev user created in both SQL Servers http://screencast.com/t/pGmnYQTZJm
- The SQL_Replication_Dev user is mapped to the publishing DB and the `distribution` DB on the publisher and the subscriber DB on the subscriber. In all instances, has the `db_owner` role assigned http://screencast.com/t/2uVfHbkf4Q
- The publication is using a network share and not the default folder http://screencast.com/t/OgnUcfBWlz
- The SQL_Replication_Dev user has `Full Control` to the share http://screencast.com/t/d5s1ZZiW
- The SQL_Replication_Dev user has `Full Control` to the underlying folder http://screencast.com/t/T6zJaku2Cob
- The SQL_Replication_Dev user is on the Public Access List (PAL) for the publication http://screencast.com/t/BQ7EEh4vfc
- Both the snapshot agent and the log reader agent are set as the SQL_Replication_Dev user http://screencast.com/t/iCpytv8yjL
- The subscription distribution agent is set to use the SQL_Replication_Dev user and impersonate http://screencast.com/t/onD82Zd1gU0B

The subscription creates successfully and fires the publication snapshot agent to successfully create a snapshot in the folder share.

When looking at the replication monitor on the publisher, I then see the OS error 53 (http://screencast.com/t/4ORyBkQUYVRg) with the detail of `The network path was not found`. The path and file exist and are accessible to the SQL_Replication_Dev user (I tested this by logging into the server and navigating to the file via the share - is that good enough?).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you navigate to the network share from the Subscriber?  So, on the Subscriber, open Windows Explorer, and type in \\ComputerName\ReplicationData\Dev, and hit Enter.  What happens?

Comment: @BrandonWilliams I am not able to access it as it's on a remote server. There is no VPN or the like. Should I be using FTP in that case? (if that's all it is - I'm feeling a bit silly :( )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I did have everything configured correctly and I ended up creating a VPN connection between the publisher and subscriber. I could then set the `Alternate Path` in the subscriber properties to \\local_ip_address_of_publisher\ReplicationDev.

As the VPN connection was only needed for the initial snapshot I could then disconnect the VPN.

In the future, should I need to pass another snapshot, I can re-connect the VPN and make sure the `Alternate Path` in the subscriber properties are set to use the new local ip address of the publisher.